# URL from Google Shopping not redirecting properly?

Tags: magento-1.9, redirect

**Magento 1.4**

I have a product with URL https://www.whatever.de/something.htm. This can be opened normally. Now, when a customer clicks on that product in Google Shopping, Google adds something to the URL which makes it look like this: https://www.whatever.de/something.htm?gad=1&gclid=Cj0KCQjwzdOlBhCNasdw45MujqC-2YMvDe8pVnvF5WzcHfU74FmpGLK_GZdRQ-h-ZCJHJPoaAomeEALw_wcB.

This URL results in an `The page isn’t redirecting properly` error in any browser. Why do the params in the URL make the difference, What must be changed in order to make it work?

Thanks!